# DataTrigger Set Template

Tags: wpf, templates, styles, datatrigger

I have to SetTemplate and I used DataTrigger but it doesn't work.

My Code :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:My_type}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GUID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyClassViewControl}}}" 
                     Value="id1">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GUID, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyClassViewControl}}}" 
                     Value="id2">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SecondTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms743659.aspx) is an example.
Why my code doesn't work ?
GUID isn't wrong ("id1" or "id2")

Comment: Make sure the MyClassViewControl that it is accessing has it's DataContext set to something that has a GUID property.  Otherwise this code looks ok I think.

Comment: The Binding is right ! MyClassViewControl has a property GUID. The DataContext seems to be ok

Comment: Is there a binding exception in the output window when you run this?

Comment: Does `MyClassViewControl` have a property called `GUID`, or does it's `DataContext` have a property called `GUID`?

Comment: No there isn't binding exception. And yes there is property GUID in MyClassViewControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : 
Create TemplateSelector in C# :

```
public class GUIDTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (item != null && element != null)
        {
            string GUID = item as string;
            if (GUID != null)
            {
                if (GUID.Equals("id1"))
                {
                    return element.FindResource("FirstTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                }
                if (GUID.Equals("id2"))
                {
                    return element.FindResource("SecondTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and in my XAML File :

```
<local:GUIDTemplateSelector x:Key="TheGUIDControlTemplateSelector"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type My_type}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:My_type}">
                <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TheGUIDTemplateSelector}" Content="{Binding GUID,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:My_type}}}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
"{Binding GUID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
      AncestorType={x:Type local:MyClassViewControl}}}"
```

should be

```
"{Binding GUID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
      AncestorType={x:Type local:MyClassViewControl}}}"
```

Comment: The biniding is ok ! I think that GUID not initialize when DataTrigger test its value.
How to wait for its initilization in XAML?